# Only index shows up when filtering a column in my dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filtering

Newbie here. I'm trying to filter specific columns to make graphs for my class, but some columns, when filtered, only displays the index of my dataframe. How can I solve this?

Main Dataframe:

[image: Main Dataframe]

Filtered Dataframe:

[image: Filtered Dataframe]

I've tried to reset and change the index already, but whenever I do, the replaced index just gets displayed instead of the column I need.

Comment: `df.filter(["GDP"])`

Comment: same issue persists.

Comment: `df.filter(like="GDP")` ?

Comment: Please provide reproducible example with copy-pastable data, not images.